# Sequelize hasOne and belongsTo relationship problem

Tags: database, postgresql, sequelize.js

i am using PostgreSQL with Sequelize ORM to create my db.

I have this models:

models.js

```
const Users = db.define("users", {
  name: {
    type: DataTypes.STRING,
  },
  lastname: {
    type: DataTypes.STRING,
  },
  sector: {
    type: DataTypes.STRING,
  },
  email: { type: DataTypes.STRING, unique: true, allowNull: false },
  password: { type: DataTypes.STRING, allowNull: false },
  points: { type: DataTypes.INTEGER, defaultValue: 0 },
  suscripcion: { type: DataTypes.BOOLEAN, defaultValue: false },
  preference_id: { type: DataTypes.STRING },
});

const Pronostico = db.define("pronosticos", {
  matchId: {
    type: DataTypes.STRING,
    unique: true,
  },
  winner: {
    type: DataTypes.STRING,
  },
  goalHome: {
    type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
  },
  goalAway: {
    type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
  },
});

//REFRESH TOKEN
const RefreshToken = db.define("refreshTokens", {
  token: {
    type: DataTypes.STRING,
  },
  expiryDate: {
    type: DataTypes.DATE,
  },
  userId: {
    type: DataTypes.STRING,
  },
});

RefreshToken.createToken = async function (user) {
  let expiredAt = new Date();
  expiredAt.setSeconds(expiredAt.getSeconds() + config.jwtRefreshExpiration);
  let _token = uuidv4();

  let refreshToken = await this.create({
    token: _token,
    userId: user.id,
    expiryDate: expiredAt.getTime(),
  });
  return refreshToken.token;
};

RefreshToken.verifyExpiration = (token) => {
  return token.expiryDate.getTime() < new Date().getTime();
};
```

This are the Relationships:

```
Users.hasMany(Pronostico, { as: "pronosticos" });
Pronostico.belongsTo(Users, { foreignKey: "userId", as: "user" });

RefreshToken.belongsTo(User, {
  foreignKey: 'userId', targetKey: 'id'
});
User.hasOne(RefreshToken, {
  foreignKey: 'userId', targetKey: 'id'
});
```

Somewhere on my server, I have this controller which creates a refreshToken:

```
let refreshToken = await RefreshToken.createToken(user);
```

The problem is that I get an error that says "column userId doesnt exist in refreshTokens relationship.

Maybe I have some issues with the relationships but I think they are OK.

Any suggestion?

Comment: Did you check that `userId` actually exists in RefreshTokens table?

Comment: @Anatoly I´ve checked in the psql shell and does not exist... But for what I know, with the relationships should automatically create it...

Comment: Check if `RefreshToken` and `User` are the same instances as `db.refreshToken` and `db.User`

Comment: I´ve edited the question, becouse I´ve forgotten to modify the relationships. There is no db.refreshToken and db.User.

Comment: Please show how you do `sync`